# Filtering a WP_Query meta_query by numeric values isn't working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, meta-query, advanced-custom-fields

That was a very dense title.

I have a custom post type "event" which has a Date/Time picker field "event_date" thanks to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. This Date/Time picker saves a UNIX timestamp to the database. I'm trying to use WP_Query to get all events that are today or in the future. This is the code that I have right now:

```
$args = Array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'        => array(
                'key'       => 'event_date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => intval(strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))),
                'type'      => 'numeric'
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It's giving me all the events, past and future.

I realize that the timestamps are stored as strings in the database so 'compare' => '>=' normally wouldn't work, but what what I've read on Google and in the Codex that 'type' => 'numeric' should cast the string to an integer and allow it to be compared with my value of this morning at midnight. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try an array of arrays in your meta query.

```
$args = Array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'        => array(
         array(
                'key'       => 'event_date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => intval(strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))),
                'type'      => 'numeric'
         )
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is also work for me for Unix Time. (You save my lot time)

Comment: +1 for 'meta_value_num' v.s. 'meta_value' for comparing timestamps which are stored as strings.

Answer (score 1):

woa, you saved my day with this answer, i was trying to filter posts by custom numeric field called type_price and i was trying to do it that way:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'type_price',
        'value' => array( 0, 500000 ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
 )),
```

but it should be this way to do it ASC:

```
array(
   'posts_per_page' => -1, 
   'meta_key' => 'type_price', 
   'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num', 
   'order' => 'ASC', 
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
                'key' => 'type_price',
                'value' => array( 0, 500000 ),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            )
        )),
```

thanks a lot :)